# Method to sort an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've been working on a method that sorts an array from lowest to highest number.
I came up with the code below but, as you probably guessed, it doesn't do what I expected.

The logic I wished to apply goes as follows:

Given I have an array, for example array {4,3,1,2,5}
The code would compare, for example, array[0] (which would be four in this case) with each element in the array,

```
array[0]>array[0] (4>4=false), 
array[0]>array[1] (4>3)= +1counter, 
array[0]>array[2] (4>1)= +1counter, 
array[0]>array[3] (4>2)= +1counter,
array[0]>array[4] (4>5=false)

counter = 3
```

So since the counter value its now 3, in the new array (array2, or arrayOrdered) number 4 would be in the third index.

How should I fix it? Any help its more than appreciated!

```
public static int[] OrderArray(int[] array)
{

    int[] array2=new int[array.length];

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        int place=0;
        for (int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if (array[i]> array[j])
            {
                place = place+1;
            }
            array2[place] = array[i];
        }

    }
    return array2;
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: Is there a good reason you aren't simply using `Arrays.sort`? (Or, `IntStream.of(array).sorted().toArray()`, or one of many other choices) (Or, trying to implement a well-known algorithm)

Comment: The method you are trying to apply here is "count the number of elements less than the i-th element; place the i-th element at the count-th position". This doesn't work, say, if you have equal elements in the input.

Comment: What if array is [4,5,1,2,3]? This algo will give you wrong result. So think in different direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do is called **sorting**, and there are many known sorting algorithms with different characteristics you can use to accomplish what you want.

You can read about many of the different sorting algorithms here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Java itself has built in sorting functionality, and you can sort an array using the `Arrays.sort` method, which uses a very fast and well known **Quicksort** algorithm for arrays of ints.

As other commentators have discussed, your sorting algorithm appears flawed, and overall appears to be closest to an **Insertion Sort** algorithm, which you may want to look at for some ideas:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

> Insertion sort iterates, consuming one input element each repetition,
>   and growing a sorted output list. At each iteration, insertion sort
>   removes one element from the input data, finds the location it belongs
>   within the sorted list, and inserts it there. It repeats until no
>   input elements remain.

Pseudocode from the above link:

```
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

Comment: I'll take a look at it for sure!
It was a homework, so part of the restrictions was not using the java methods nor recurssion, amongst others, but after working on this I see how useful that is!
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
int place=0;
        for (int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if (array[i]> array[j])
            {
                place = place+1;
            }
            array2[place] = array[i];
        }
```

You updated array2[place] every time, whereas it should be updated after you looped through the array.
Thus 
`array2[place] = array[i];`
This shoud be outside the second for loop

```
int place=0;
        for (int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if (array[i]> array[j])
            {
                place = place+1;
            }

        }
array2[place] = array[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int[] array = { 2, 1, 3, 5, 4 };
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( array ) );

        int[] orderedArray = Arrays.stream( array )
            .sorted()
            .toArray();
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( orderedArray ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not check all corner case to assure your logic is correct but for sure the line:

```
array2[place] = array[i];
```

should be outside of the second for block. Your code overwrites all good inserts in array2 currently.

Working implementation:

```
public static int[] OrderArray(int[] array){

  int[] array2=new int[array.length];
  for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
  {
      int place=0;
      for (int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
      {
          if (array[i]> array[j])
          {
              place = place+1;
          }
      }
      array2[place] = array[i];
  }
  return array2;
}
```

Comment: "Correct implementation:" this isn't correct. See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929683/method-that-organizes-an-array-in-java#comment102277244_57929683).

Comment: Can you really claim that a broken algorithm has a working implementation?

Comment: no idea actually. what would you call it if not for working? I tried to answer the question "how to fix" by pointing out the biggest flaw in the logic.

Comment: "what would you call it if not for working?" Not working, broken, incorrect, defective etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you are ready to make the decision where to place it. You should do it outside of the loop where it determines the position for an element

```java
public static int[] OrderArray(int[] array)
{

    int[] array2=new int[array.length];

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        int place=0;
        for (int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if (array[i]> array[j])
            {
                place = place+1;
            }
        }
      array2[place] = array[i];
    }
    return array2;
}
```

I made a simple test for your algorithm and it fails in 1\3 out of 100 test cases. Mostly because test case has 

1) Duplicates

2) Zero

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int failed = 0;
        int succeeded = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            //"Unordered array"
            int[] unOrdArr = new int[10];
            for (int j = 0; j < unOrdArr.length; j++) {
                int val = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
                unOrdArr[j] = val;
            }
            //Sorted by suggested algorithm
            int [] ordArr = orderArray(unOrdArr);
            //Sorted by internal lib
            int [] intrnSortArr = Arrays.copyOf(unOrdArr, unOrdArr.length);
            Arrays.sort(intrnSortArr);
            if(Arrays.equals(ordArr, intrnSortArr)) {
                succeeded++;
            } else {
                failed++;
                System.out.println("Failed");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unOrdArr));
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ordArr));
                System.out.println("---------");
            };
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully sorted: " + succeeded);
        System.out.println("Failed to sort: " + failed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that heap sort, merge sort, or quick sort are faster than the type of sort used in the question.

I updated vmarinescu's code with a third array used to handle duplicates. Note this is a slow method.

```
public static int[] OrderArray(int[] array){
    int[] array2=new int[array.length];
    int[] stored=new int[array.length];     // used to handle duplicates
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        int place=0;
        for (int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if (array[i]> array[j])
                place = place+1;
        }
        while(stored[place] != 0)           // skip duplicates
            place += 1;
        array2[place] = array[i];
        stored[place] = 1;
    }
    return array2;
}
```

---

As an alternative, cycle sort is similar, but sorts in place (it doesn't need a second array).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort

```
public static void cyclesort(int a[])
{
int n = a.length;
int i, j, p;                            // used for indexing
int e, t;                               // used to hold array elements
    for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        e = a[j];                       // e = 1st element of a cycle
        p = j;                          // p = position to store e
        for(i = j+1; i < n; i++){       // advance p to 1st element >= e
            if(a[i] < e)
                p += 1;
        }
        if(p == j)                      // if p not changed, e is in place
            continue;                   //   continue with next element
        while(e == a[p])                // skip any duplicates
            p += 1;
        t = a[p];                       // swap(e, a[p])
        a[p] = e;
        e = t;                          //   e = next element in this cycle
        while(p != j){                  // continue this cycle
            p = j;
            for(i = j+1; i < n; i++){   //   advance p to 1st element >= e
                if(a[i] < e)
                    p += 1;
            }
            while(e == a[p])            //   skip any duplicates
                p += 1;
            t = a[p];                   //   swap(e, a[p])
            a[p] = e;
            e = t;                      //     e = next element in this cycle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh I hadn't considered duplicates! Thanks, that code is very useful

Answer (score 0):

I made a video on [youtube](https://youtu.be/6r6aMp6dLAs) look at hawaiideveloper's solution:

```
package SortingArrayFun;
```

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortAnArrayAscending {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] originalArray = {13, 54, 60, 33, 20, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 23}; // The original Array
    int totalOfElements = originalArray.length; // Counts the amount of elements in this array which should be 13
    System.out.println("The amount of elements in this array is: " + originalArray.length);
    

    for(int outerLoopCounter = 0; outerLoopCounter <= totalOfElements;  outerLoopCounter++) { // we need this to cycle the same amount of times
        //as the totalOfElements
            for(int leftIndexer = 0;  leftIndexer < (totalOfElements -1);  leftIndexer++) { // this does the action of moving the index to the left
                int rightIndexer = leftIndexer + 1; // this will make the index go right
                int positionA = originalArray[leftIndexer]; // store the output of each element that comes from the left pointer aka left index
                int positionB = originalArray[rightIndexer]; // store the output of each element that comes from the right pointer aka right index
                
                        //Control Flow aka Decision Maker if position B is less than position A... please swap them
                                if(positionB < positionA) { // control flow 
                                        originalArray[leftIndexer] = positionB; // then swap them and make position on the right go to position on left
                                        originalArray[rightIndexer] = positionA; // do the opposite of what position B does
                }
        }
}
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalArray));  //prints the array on one line
    
}
```

}